# TypeError: execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multi'

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to delete a record in database using MySQLdb module. 
In https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html, I found multi=True for executing multiple quires in execution but it generates error. Can someone help me knowing that what I am missing?

```
query = "DELETE FROM Service_Machine WHERE Id=(SELECT Id FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");" \
        "DELETE FROM Machine_Usage WHERE Id=(SELECT Id FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");" \
                    "DELETE FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");"
print(query)
self.cursor.execute(query, multi=True)
```

Comment: Literal duplicate of [Why unexpected keyword 'multi' in Python's MySQLdb module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322523/why-unexpected-keyword-multi-in-pythons-mysqldb-module)