# Why unexpected keyword 'multi' in Python's MySQLdb module?

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to delete a record in database using MySQLdb module. In https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html, I found `multi=True` for executing multiple queries in execution but it generates error. Can someone help me knowing that what I am missing?

```
query = "DELETE FROM Service_Machine WHERE Id=(SELECT Id FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");" \
        "DELETE FROM Machine_Usage WHERE Id=(SELECT Id FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");" \
        "DELETE FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");
print(query)
self.cursor.execute(query, multi=True)
```

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice, even if you get no answer.

Answer (score 7):

[`MySQLdb`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/) and
[`mysql-connector`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) are two
separate, independent MySQL database adapters for Python.

Both of these adapters conform to the the [DB API specification versions 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).
The `multi` keyword parameter is not part of the standard DB API, and is not part of `MySQLdb`'s API.

Only the `mysql-connector`'s [`execute` method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) has the `multi` keyword parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InSql1 = "DELETE FROM Service_Machine WHERE Id=(SELECT Id FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");" 
InSql2 = "DELETE FROM Machine_Usage WHERE Id=(SELECT Id FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");" 
InSql3 =  "DELETE FROM Machines WHERE Id="+id+");
#print(query)

self.cursor.execute(InSql1)
self.cursor.execute(InSql2)
self.cursor.execute(InSql3)
self.cursor.execute("Commit;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method instead

```
try:
    cur.execute(query1)
    cur.execute(query2)
    cur.execute(query150)
    con.commit()
except Exception as e:
    con.rollback()
```